# What is the tangential velocity of a cylinder which is moving with a translational/ linear velocity (of center of mass)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

Let a cylinder is made to roll in such a way that the velocity of its center of mass is **$v$ $m/s$**. Are the particles of its surface supposed to move with equivalent tangential velocity? It is to be noted that the cylinder is rolling on a non frictional surface(negligible amount of friction).Isn't tangential  velocity independent on translational velocity in this circumstance?

The scenario is like the cylinder is being taken from one place to another along a flat surface by rolling it and with respect to a stationary object like a tree its linear velocity is v m/s

Comment: I don't get what is meant by "rolling on a non frictional surface".

Comment: negligible amount of friction

Comment: Then it can't be rolling "on the surface". It is *rotating* adjacent to the surface.

Comment: Related (meta): *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478)*. Someone else can elaborate.

Comment: I rolledback your last edit, because you have accepted an answer and it matches the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I want to imply first is that rolling motion **cannot** happen on a frictionless surface (neglegible friction). It merely slides if no friction. Then the all particles are moving with $v$ linear velocity. If the friction is enough to provide external torque for rolling motion, then we can analyze it as a combination of two motions: *linear motion* and *rotational motion*. The all particles has the same $v$ linear velocity. And every particle on the same circumference has the same tangential velocity. If it is a rolling without slipping motion, the bottommost particle has zero velocity, therefore tangential velocity is equal to linear velocity and they are opposite in direction.<sup>[[1]](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/%7Emalkan/astro8/physics1a/rolling.htm#:%7E:text=An%20important%20point%20to%20remember,thing%20will%20simply%20slide%20along.&text=To%20get%20pure%20rolling%20motion,times%20the%20coefficient%20of%20friction.)</sup>

Comment: could you please explain the latter part of your answer further?

Comment: I added a link to my answer. Check that please.

Comment: Are you implying that pure rolling cannot occur on a frictionless surface? Because that is incorrect.

Comment: @Reet , please check this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/515259/305718

Comment: @ACB your point being? A cylinder of radius $r$ on a frictionless surface with $v_{CM}=v_0$ and $\omega = v_0/r$ will pure roll without the need for friction.

Comment: @Reet are you confusing "rolling" with "rotating"? "Rolling" implies there is another agent: i.e. a friction surface, and a gravitation or other pull.

Comment: @WeatherVane " **Rolling where there is no sliding is referred to as pure rolling** ." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling . I have never heard of the notion that rolling implies the existence of another agent.

Comment: @Reet the cylinder cannot roll without *another agent* to make it roll. Suppose you release a stationary cylinder on an inclined plane under gravity. If there is no friction, it will not roll: it will slide just as a rectangular section would. There needs to be friction with *another agent* to make the cylinder roll.

Comment: @MSKB If you are not getting the latter part of my answer, see this too. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/660678/305718 (not the exact situation, but it may help)

Comment: i edited my wues a bit...... I am now considering for a frictional surface

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed I agree. But see my second comment. Will that case, on a horizontal surface, not produce pure rolling?

Comment: Please don't edit questions that makes its answers invalid. If you want ask a new question.(but your new question has been asked numerous times on PSE)

Answer (score 1):

Instantaneously:

- a particle in contact with the ground has velocity $0$
- a particle on the opposite end of that diameter (at the top) will have a velocity $2v$.

The locus of any point on the cylinder is a **cycloid**.

[image]

From [Rolling Circles](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/RolllingCircle/RollCircle.html)